# How to concatenate two separate colums into one?

Tags: custom-post-types, sql, geo-data

In phpmyadmin I have two separate columns for latitude and longitude.

e.g. lat: '38.897683' lng:'-77.03649'.

These coordinates are generated for my location custom posts.

How can I automatically merge them into a new (third) column so that I have the values in one string:

'38.897683,-77.03649'.

I would like to apply this to both the preexisting and new posts that are created.

Thaks

Comment: Are you looking for a pure SQL query right?

Comment: What does your table definition look like?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo If the SQL query is able to run every-time a new post is created that would be perfect , but from my research before asking this question I haven't been able to find one, only a query that affects what is already existing. (PS-Honestly i wasn't sure whether to put this on the main stackverflow site or this wordpress specific site).

Comment: Mmmm, now I understand, I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for a *pure* SQL solutions for this. You can achieve this by running the following query:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET latitude_longitude = CONCAT(latitude, ", " , longitude);
```

That will work for you, just double check the name of the columns: `latitude_longitude`, `latitude` and `longitude`.

---

**Update**

If you want to run that SQL query each time a post is saved you can use a [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) as shown below:

```php
function update_post_location( $post_id ) {

    // If this is just a revision, do not update.
    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $query = 'UPDATE wp_posts ' . 
             'SET latitude_longitude = CONCAT(latitude, ", " , longitude) ' .
             'WHERE id = ' . $post_id;

    $wpdb->query( $query )
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_location' );
```

Comment: hi, sorry for the very long reply. Your tip worked. many thanks